# Duplicate Answer without new key idea (but merely a readability improvement, etc..)

Tags: discussion

I notice there are some users who regularly rewrite past answer as a new one.

The user created a duplicated answer with an improvement on the language for readability, however I find that it doesn't improve the key idea of the answer to the question. The problem is that creating new answer without a new idea will only waste everyone time reading it. I find that this could be solved by editing the past answer. Not only the credit given to the original author who answer it, but also it save the time to read one unique answer for each question.

For example: This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245190/kasper-souren) rewrote some past answers and instead of editing/improving the past answer, he create it as a new answer. I believe many more other users.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31642070/764592
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20768795/764592
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33076157/764592
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31296120/764592
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38287020/764592
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20768800/764592

Is this an acceptable in SO communities?

Comment: How is the first link an example of this behavior?

Comment: @Will It's an adaptation of someone else's answer; see the last paragraph.

Comment: @Will *Use this package `unicodecsv`*

Comment: I'm unable to see a problem here. We have similar answers all the time. For many technical problems,  there's not that many different approaches to a solution. Ideally, the answer that is better put, clearer, has more detail, offers explanations and examples, etc. etc. wins. Those things make it a *completely different answer* even if the key idea is the same. You don't change other people's posts into something completely different

Comment: @Pekka웃 does this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33076157/764592) even make sense to be a completely new answer for you? Well, everyone could just start summarizing each of everyone answer and make it nicer into point form, so everyone happy to look into just the summarized answer.

Comment: @Yeo no, you're right, that's not a good use of the answering facility. It looks more like a misunderstanding of how the system works rather than systematic abuse though. I left a comment suggesting the answer be deleted.

Comment: seems no actions can take except exact duplicates, we may never know whether users generate their answer independently or just converting already present answers into their own versions

Answer (score 1):

> The user created a duplicated answer with an improvement on the language for readability, however I find that it doesn't improve the key idea of the answer to the question. The problem is that creating new answer without a new idea will only waste everyone time reading it.

Sounds like you feel that that answer isn't useful.  When you feel that an answer isn't useful you have a *fantastic* tool at your disposal to effectively convey that feedback.  Downvote it.

Comment: Well, the answer technically correct, but I am not in position to downvote a legit valid answer with a better readability, etc... But surely he/she could simply edit the past answer

Comment: @Yeo You have more than 125 rep, so you *do* in fact have the ability to downvote an answer that you think isn't useful.  Whether the answer is correct is just *one* factor.  You should vote based on whether or not the answer is *useful*, not whether or not it is factually correct.  No, he couldn't just edit someone else's answer to change what he would want it to be.  He could comment on those answers, or post one of his own.  If you don't feel that the new answer is preferable, or that the answer is worth the changes, you can reflect that in your vote.

Comment: Yes, The new answer is preferable, but only if the past answer get deleted or removed, because it is duplicated. It feel bad when someone overwrite your original answer and earn the credit. So, based on your statement, I will have to upvote the new answer since it is better.

Comment: @Yeo If the new answer is superior, and is more useful than the other answer, then that would be deserved.  If it's *not* more useful, then you should reflect that with your vote.  When you refuse to downvote people for providing content that *you don't think is useful* then you're encouraging them to continue that behavior that you don't think is useful.

Comment: In very strictly speaking, I think there is no solution specific to this behaviour, since downvote an answer just because it is very similar to previous one is violating the usage of votes, because it results in voting depends on another answer, not the current content of answer only.

Comment: @amuse It results in voting *based on the usefulness of the answer*, which is *exactly how you're supposed to vote*.  If an answer isn't useful, because it's just duplicating the content of another, then your vote should reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

In the first linked example, the nominal "original" answer was practically a link-only answer. It says, "hey, you can use that package over there". The nominal "duplicate" answer says "hey, you can use that package over there, **here's how**". It's the "here's how" that makes it such a better answer than the other that it deserves the votes the other one did not get.

For others, the only problematic answers were these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20768795/764592
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20768800/764592

But that's because they copied the exact same answer to both questions, when in fact they should have perhaps closed the questions as duplicates, or at least tailored the answer to each question.